# Error while building KDE LabPlot on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, bison, kde-plasma

I am trying to build KDE LabPlot but it shows an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):  
  Could NOT find BISON (missing: BISON_EXECUTABLE)  
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)  
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBISON.cmake:226 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)  
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (find_package)
```

I've already installed Bison and the command

`apt-cache show bison | grep -i version` shows the following output:

```
Version: 2:3.0.4.dfsg-1  
Version: 2:2.7.1.dfsg-2
```

Can someone please help me fix it!

Comment: Note: This has nothing to do with 'kdevelop', which refers to the KDevelop IDE (I removed the tag now)

Comment: Regarding your build issue: Did you try a completely fresh build directory?